# how to fix width of child div tag

Tags: css

I have two div tags `parent` and `child`. `child` tag has position fixed with width 100%. Parent has padding of 10px as show in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q4ffs/) code. The issue is that when I give width of 100% to child tag then its right side moves out of parent div tag. I know that is because it has padding. One way to solve this is to give child tag a width of 90%. `But is there a better way than this so that child tag appears exactly inside parent tag?`

**UPDATE**

I want to keep position: fixed for child tag

```
.parent {
    height: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.child {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100px; width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black; 
}
```

Comment: The padding is not the problem as you suggest in your post. Test it with no padding. Personally think fixed positioning is rarely a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**jsfiddle.net/q4ffs/3/ DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/q4ffs/3/)

If you are comfortable with a little use of jQuery then this should fix your issue. CSS still have some limitations but this little line of javascript may serve you well.

```
  $(function (){
      $('.child').each(function (){
          $(this).css('width', $(this).parent('div').width());
      })
  });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Place the `absolute` div inside another div which is placed inside the parent div.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="newDiv">
    <div class="child">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The other div will get the `position:relative;`.

```
.newDiv
{
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
}
.child {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px; left:0; right:0;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mZTFq/)

Comment: I want to keep position: fixed. I do not want to change the position attribute of child tag.

Comment: You said in your question `absolute`, but either way, you can't have a `fixed` div according to another div, the `fixed` div will always be fixed according to the whole page.

Comment: If fixed position is is fixed according to the whole page then why in my jsfiddle it is positioned inside parent div tag? Because I placed is inside parent div tag and it is position to its parent's top left corner. But it is the width which is a big issue here.

Comment: @x4ph4r Because normally it would take its default position in the layout, check this fiddle, I gave the parent a `100px`, notice that the fixed div will stretch 100% in width according to the page, and not the parent div. http://jsfiddle.net/BjqrT/

Answer (score 0):

Make the Postion to relative see the output

```
.parent {
    height: 300px;
    padding: 10px;   
    border: 1px solid red;

}

.child {
    position: relative;
    height: 100px; width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also adjust its padding if padding is the problem

give class padding to child

and append the code

```
.padding /*for box padding ie padding inside the box*/
{
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */

    }
```

it dont let the child to maximize her width with padding

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use width is 100vw and set margin-left:-10px ; on the child.

Cheers